# What is a good .gitignore to use with Rails on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

What is a good .gitignore to use with Rails on Heroku?

```
*.log  
*.sqlite3
```

what else?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is pretty similar to: [Rails: exclude anything from version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969393/rails-exclude-anything-from-version-control) Here is my answer from that.

DHH just [posted on Twitter](http://twitter.com/dhh/status/7107817801) that there will be a [default .gitignore](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a642edbef31fe96fad488accf0052653c573e8db) in Rails 3, which includes:

```
db/*.sqlite3
log/*.log
tmp/**/*
```

This is usually what I exclude. Some people also like to exclude the database.yml file if it's going on a public repo and you don't want to expose your database passwords.

Answer (score 11):

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore

> ```
> *.rbc
> capybara-*.html
> .rspec
> /log
> /tmp
> /db/*.sqlite3
> /db/*.sqlite3-journal
> /public/system
> /coverage/
> /spec/tmp
> **.orig
> rerun.txt
> pickle-email-*.html
>
> # TODO Comment out this rule if you are OK with secrets being uploaded to the repo
> config/initializers/secret_token.rb
>
> # Only include if you have production secrets in this file, which is no longer a Rails default
> # config/secrets.yml
>
> # dotenv
> # TODO Comment out this rule if environment variables can be committed
> .env
>
> ## Environment normalization:
> /.bundle
> /vendor/bundle
>
> # these should all be checked in to normalize the environment:
> # Gemfile.lock, .ruby-version, .ruby-gemset
>
> # unless supporting rvm < 1.11.0 or doing something fancy, ignore this:
> .rvmrc
>
> # if using bower-rails ignore default bower_components path bower.json files
> /vendor/assets/bower_components
> *.bowerrc
> bower.json
>
> # Ignore pow environment settings
> .powenv
>
> # Ignore Byebug command history file.
> .byebug_history
> ```

Comment: Awesome, glad to see a bunch of my favorite frameworks in there!

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that Heroku's slug compiler has a very similar feature using a file named `.slugignore`. This file syntax is *roughly* the same as in `.gitignore`.

So you can continue working as usual (ie: storing PSD files, spreadsheets and other common files) but remove them at runtime *on* Heroku to lower the slug's size (< 20MB sounds good).

Comment: Awesome. But the `.slugignore` file will remove them once they have been uploaded. So you will still end up uploading large files beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on Github dedicated to storing accurate gitignore files for different languages, editors, etc.  While the project does not currently have an entry specific to Heroku, you might still find it useful to review.  The project is [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore) and the Rails .gitignore is [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore).

FYI, I first found out about this project from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824188/git-ignore-vim-temporary-files) Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

On Heroku, the best starting option is:

```
db/
log/
test/
tmp/
```